# jquery video player that should support all video formats

Tags: jquery, html, video, html5-video

I have a PHP based web page, where I have to show a dump folder videos, I have checked different plugins like HTML5 etc.

PROBLEM: I am not able to show all the video formats in browser, as it says *format not supported/No compatible source was found for this media* . I have video in single format (as Listed below) not in multiple formats as HTML5 doc needs.

If you can suggest a plugin through which I can run all these or majority of these video formats then it will solve my problem.

HTML5 sample code:

```
<video width="370" height="214"  id="demo<?= $k;?>">
    <source src="www.example.com/video.avi" type="video/avi">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

I have videos in one of these formats

- mp4
- MTS
- AVI
- MOV
- mpg
- m4v
- mkv
- mpeg
- webm
- wmv

If a chrome extension is required then I can add that too on user pc.

Comment: If you are using HTML5 `<video>` tag your choices are limited to webm, mp4, and ogv. You could convert incompatible formats with [XMedia Recode Video Converter](https://www.xmedia-recode.de/en/) or let users download the videos.

Comment: OK. Any jquery plugin which can cover these formats?

Comment: Yes, but they are WordPress plugins. I'm pretty sure the miracle plugins that claim to play everything uses Flash. If you're not worried about iPhone and iPad users you can use Flash but it will be discontinued in 2020. [*Free Video Hosting Guide*](https://www.free-video-hosting.net/) has tutorials on embedding video by using Flash swf video files.

Comment: One more solution comes to mind is to [host video via YouTube or Vimeo](https://www.dummies.com/software/adobe/dreamweaver/how-to-use-youtube-vimeo-and-other-online-services-to-host-videos-in-dreamweaver/).

Comment: I would use something like ffmpeg to convert your source files into a single consistent validated format and avoid plugins and bolt-ons

Comment: @zer00ne can't host videos anywhere ! need a solution in web page or chrome extension will help

Comment: @Offbeatmammal already using ffmpeg to convert video in lowres and in same format. I tried that but then I am not able to covert it into lowres

Comment: @RoeDummy so what is the exact nature of this webpage? You say that you can't host videos...yet you want video on a webpage...?

Comment: @zer00ne ,, Sorry it needs some correction. It is a webpage which is not public and used by an office also hosted internally